# vue-router works on local but not on my server

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am developing a web application with vue-js.I use vue-router (4.2.4 version).
I made routage between some pages, in local all works perfectly, but went I upload my project on my server I have a 404 error when I try to access routing-page, whereas the project seems to work fine other than that.

For example :

http://localhost:8080/Tiffauges/edit --> works

https://laurianegelebart.fr/Tiffauges/edit --> 404 error

It is the first time I made routage so maybe I made a stupid mistake but I don't know where.
My vue.config.js is like that :

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/Tiffauges/'
}
```

My main.js is like that :

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from './pages/Home.vue';
import Edit from './pages/EditJSON.vue';
import Machine from './pages/Machine.vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './data/store';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/Tiffauges/edit',
    name: 'Edit',
    component: Edit
  },
  {
    path: '/Tiffauges/machine/:name',
    name: 'Machine',
    component: Machine
  }, 
  {
    path: '/Tiffauges/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  }
];


const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.mount('#app');
```

A strange thing is that a part of my routage works also on the server because this part (on a gallery component) works :

```js
<router-link v-for="machine in machines" :key="machine.name" :to="{
          name: 'Machine',
          params: {
            name: machine.name
          }
        }">
```

If you want to check all the project, here is my github :
https://github.com/LaurianeGelebart/TiffaugesApp

My server is a classic ovh web server. And to upload the project I run npm run build and upload the dist directory's content on 'Tiffauges' folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that if I add directly a .htacess on my Tiffauges folder my problem is solved.
The .htacess is like that:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /Tiffauges/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /Tiffauges/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

The reason is that I need to configure my server to redirect all requests to my index.html file so that my vue router can handle the routing on the client-side. This .htaccess file will redirect all requests to /Tiffauges/index.html, allowing the router to handle the routing.